# Dev env files created in Prod env

Tags: symfony

I'm running my symfony2 project in prod environment, I've executed :

```
rm-rf app/cache/dev
rm-rf app/cache/prod
```

When I visit one of ma pages (cache created), I find files in dev folder.
the folders created are: 
[image]

Can you explain why to me.

This is my config file

```
 Config.yml


imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
framework:
    profiler:
        enabled: true
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 43200
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
salva_jshrink:
    flaggedComments: true
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~


# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    # transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    # host:      "%mailer_host%"
    # username:  "%mailer_user%"
    # password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            metadata_cache_driver:
                type: memcached
                class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache
                host: localhost
                port: 11211
                instance_class: Memcached           
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
```

Comment: Can you show us your `config.yml`?

Comment: I added the config.yml

Comment: that `profiler: enabled: true` looks highly suspicious to be found in `config.yml`. Maybe you want to put it in `config_dev.yml`?